# RabbitMQ Consumer

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am playing with RabbitMQ and .NET and found myself duplicating the connection initialization logic in all of the consumers.

Created the `Consumer` in order to avoid that and add some tracing. 
It's far away from anything usable, but wanted to hear ideas/opinions/alternatives.

```
public class Consumer
{
  private static readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  public event EventHandler<CanonicalModel> OnReceive;
  private IModel _exchange;

  public void Init(string incoming = "#")
  {
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
      using (_exchange = connection.CreateModel())
      {
        _exchange.ExchangeDeclare("exchange_name", "topic");
        var queueName = _exchange.QueueDeclare().QueueName;
        _exchange.QueueBind(queueName, "queue_name", incoming);

        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(_exchange);
        _exchange.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

        while (true)
        {
          var ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
          var model = new CanonicalModel(ea.Body); 

          _logger.Info(new { Time = DateTime.Now, Type = "IN", Value = "..." });

          var startTime = DateTime.Now;
          if (OnReceive != null)
          {
            OnReceive(this, model);
          }

          _logger.Info(new { Time = DateTime.Now, Type = "CONTROL", Value = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Milliseconds });
        }
      }
  }

  public void Publish(string routingKey, CanonicalModel model)
  {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

    _logger.Info(new { Time = DateTime.Now, Type = "OUT", Value = "..." });
    _exchange.BasicPublish("exchange_name", routingKey, null, message);
  }
}
```

Console application which uses a consumer.

```
class ConsoleConsumer
{
  private const string SERVICENAME = "CONSUMER_FOO";
  private const string INCOMING = "foo";
  private const string OK = "success";
  private const string FAIL = "fail";
  private static Consumer _consumer;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    Console.WriteLine(" [Running] {0} ...", SERVICENAME);

    _consumer = new Consumer();
    _consumer.OnReceive += Process;
    _consumer.Init(INCOMING);

  }

  public static void Process(object sender, CanonicalModel model)
  {
    var result = true;
    var outRoutingKey = result ? OK : FAIL;

    _consumer.Publish(outRoutingKey, model);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the consumer as a consumer and not as an initializer--which means I would split all the initialization logic out into a separate class that takes in parameters and returns your `IModel`. That way you can pass the `IModel` directly into the consumer already initialized.

You also might want to consider using the observer pattern and the .NET [`IObserver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx)/[`IObservable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) interfaces if you are looking for a layer of abstraction.